# Form Recognizer label tool request form link appears to be broken

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to request the Label Tool to help with training a new form, but the link on the tutorial site appears to be incorrect. It redirects to the main Microsoft site.

I am working off [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool) and using the link under the second bullet point of Prerequisites.

https://aka.ms/LabelToolRequestAccess is the url that is on that link.

I'd like to try using this tool rather than training using Python. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link https://aka.ms/LabelToolRequestAccess is working on my side, see capture below:

[image: opened link]

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like they have fixed the link.